# How do you mass rename files in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

there are 30 files named like this:

```
sample_kmer_41_2.lib1.bowtie.file1.27.faabyss_sample
```

I need the output to be:

```
abyss_sample_kmer_41_2.lib1.bowtie.file1.27.fa
```

I don't know how to do this, I've already screwed the names up a lot. thanks for any help.

Comment: Use the `rename` command, it allows you to provide a regular expression substitution command.

Comment: Oh, cool.  I learn something on here every day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Perl-based `prename` (possibly named `rename`) command, then:

```
prename 's/(.*)abyss_sample$/abyss_$1/' sample_kmer_*
```

The exact regex to use depends on how the names have been damaged.  This should work for the example name given; it may need tweaking to work with other names.

Comment: I greatly prefer this answer to my own!

Answer (score 4):

Use the `rename` utility:

```
rename 's/(.*)\.fa(.*)_sample$/$2_$1/' *
```

`rename` is part of the perl package and is installed by default on debian-like systems.  There is a different and incompatible `rename` utility that is provided as part of the `util-linux` packages.

Comment: This is also a better alternative over the Bash script that I provided.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I believe I have the incompatible rename utility and not the perl package - I tried rename before asking this question and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop.  Since I'm always nervous about this stuff I'd recommend doing an echo first to make sure everything looks groovy...

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in sample_kmer_41_2*abyss_sample ; do
  NEWNAME=`echo $FILE | sed -e 's/abyss_sample//'`
  echo mv $FILE $NEWNAME
done
```

Provided that doesn't need tweaking, you can remove the `echo` or make modifications as necessary.

Comment: Sure.  The first one takes the current filename in the loop and sends it through sed to strip off the end of the file name.  The second one simply prints `mv $FILE $NEWNAME` at the console.  Echo will "echo" back at you whatever you give it to standard output.

Comment: @David Hoelzer It won't run unless a semicolon is put before `do` and the equal sign is stripped of spaces from both sides.